# Best way to change fileList in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7, filelist

Im making an web app for my ojt and they require me to add a delete function to a file field. Like if I choose to  upload 3 of them there would be a preview to those file and I can remove some of them.

Can I just edit the fileField?
Example document.getElementbyID("field").files returns a filefield
Can I change that?

if not what is the best way to do it.

Comment: Can you share some code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Create a FormData object from your form Element and use it to handle the fields

```js
const form = document.getElementById("your_form");
const data = new FormData(form);
data.delete("file_field_name");
```

Comment: i think this will delete all the file inside the file field. all of  the files im talking about are in the same file field. I already sove it.
tnx for the answer though